# jquery selectors on $(this)

Tags: jquery, this

If I have an input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product" id="product" /><label for="product">Product</label>
```

How can I tell when it is checked using **$(this)**?

```
$('input#product').click(function() {
        console.log('clicked or not clicked?');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.is` with the `:checked` selector.

As a side note, you should not use `tag#id`; since IDs are unique, `#id` suffices.

```
$('#product').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

    console.log(checked);
});
```

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I personally prefer not to mix plain DOM and jQuery, just for consistency. Of course `this.checked` would work just as well.

Comment: That seems pointless. jQuery is a supplement to core JS DOM manipulation, not a replacement for it.

Answer (score 5):

**Using the element property:**

`this.checked`

---

**Using [`jQuery.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**:

```
$(this).prop('checked');
```

---

From the jQuery documentation (on `$.prop()`):

> *The preferred cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to check for a "truthy" value on the element's property
>   using one of the following:*
>
> - `if ( elem.checked )`
> - `if ( $(elem).prop("checked") )`
> - `if ( $(elem).is(":checked") )`

Comment: not seen prop before, is there any benefit over using "attr", or is":checked" ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Check out the table on the docs - it gives an explanation of what various functions will return. I updated my answer with a quote that might address your question about `is:checked`. I'm not sure if there's a benefit to using any one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).attr('checked');
```

or

```
$(this).is(':checked');
```

or

```
this.checked;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this

`this.checked; // here this points to the checkbox element which has a checked property`

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr('checked')`

You can also check or uncheck by using `$(this).attr('checked',false|true)`